# Sub domains not showing for android device

Tags: android, express, heroku, dns, subdomain

I'm developing a website with various sub-domains, I'm using express to handle sub-domain call like so:

```
var subdomain_url = req.subdomains[req.subdomains.length - 1];
if (subdomain_url === 'www') {
    var subdomain_url = req.subdomains[req.subdomains.length - 2];
    if (subdomain_url === 'sub1') {
        res.render('sub1');
    } else if (subdomain_url === 'sub2') {
        res.render('sub2');
    } else {
        res.render('index')
    }
} else if (subdomain_url === 'sub1') {
    res.render('sub1');
} else if (subdomain_url === 'sub2') {
    res.render('sub2');
} else {
    res.render('index');
}
```

After configuring DNS records and deploying the site works great for desktops and laptops (Windus 10) i.e the site load for mysite.com, sub1.mysite.com, sub2.mysite.com, however when using chrome over android device it only loads mysite.com and I'm getting: "This site can't be reached" for sub1.mysite.com, etc.
I tried checking out a number of reasons for this behavior but honestly I just do not understand this problem.

Would love your help, thank you!

Comment: How recently did you edit the DNS? It's possible the DNS for the other sub-domains has just not propagated to the DNS server the android is using.

Comment: days ago... I don't this it's a propagation issue

Comment: yeah a day ago shouldn't be your issue then.